# How can I apply a texture to a single mesh face?

Tags: texturing, materials

What is a simple way to apply a texture to a specific face of a mesh?

Answer (score 0):

- In vertex edit mode, mark seams, uv project, add texture, use the uvmap setting.
- Seams are difficult to see.  They are necessary to get separation of faces for free movement of the image plane off the uv image editor
- In uv editor only the target face should remain on the image area, all other faces can be moved to the side
- Material Texture .. Image Mapping Extension must be << Clip >>
- In the images below a cube has been modified and the target face is shaped into a trapezoid.  The base color is red.   Only one face has the texture.

[image]

[image]